# Javascript: "Source Code is not available for this location" msg while debugging with IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to debug some issue using IE 8 developer tools.

However after running the below code, the debugger throws error "Source Code not available for this location"

```
 window.onload = function() {
  tabberAutomatic(tabberArgs);
};
```

What does it mean ?

Above code is part of below code which basically runs the function tabberAutomatic once the document has finished loading:

```
/* This function adds tabberAutomatic to the window.onload event,
     so it will run after the document has finished loading.
  */
  var oldOnLoad;

  if (!tabberArgs) { tabberArgs = {}; }

  /* Taken from: http://simon.incutio.com/archive/2004/05/26/addLoadEvent */

  oldOnLoad = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = function() {
      tabberAutomatic(tabberArgs);
    };
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      oldOnLoad();
      tabberAutomatic(tabberArgs);
    };
  }
```

I am trying to debug issue explained in my previous question [browser showing progress bar as still progressing even when the page is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8501664/887235)

Thanks for inputs!!

Comment: @mgraph: As I have mentioned, the error I have mentioned comes after the execution of the line. i.e. after the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at the right file in the debugger?

Have you tried this, it explains alot: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes. I am looking at the right file. However, good link. Thanks!